# Annotation of multiple types of annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I want to be able to annotate a class with a list of 2 types of annotations which are related in function, but are completely different in arguments. The order of this list matters though. I have tried looking for this already, but was unable to find any references to this (I was not sure what to call this).

**Edit:**

What I want to be able to do in the end:

```
//place holder for example (Abstract)
public @interface A {
}

@Target(PARAMETER)
public @interface B extends A {
    //Gets stuff
    Class type();
    int key();
}

@Target(PARAMETER)
public @interface FlaggedListOfA extends A {
    //List of A
    A[] set();
}

//Goal is to have annotation that does this
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface ImportantFunc {
    A[] dataForA() default {};
    String[] names();
    int property() default 0;
    //etc.
}

//End goal:
public class SomeImportantClass {

    @ImportantFunc(dataForA = {@B(...), @B(...}, ...)
    public void doStuff() {

    }

    //So I can have an end goal of this (Order matters, may contain repeats,
    //and has unknown length!)
    @ImportantFunc(dataForA = {@B(...), @FlaggedListOfA(@B(...), @B(...))}, ...)
    public void doStuffB() {

    }

    @ImportantFunc(dataForA = {@FlaggedListOfA(@B(...)), @FlaggedListOfA(@B(...), @B(...))}, ...)
    public void doStuffC() {

    }

    @ImportantFunc(dataForA = {@FlaggedListOfA(@B(...), @FlaggedListOfA(@B(...), @B(...))), @B(...)}, ...)
    public void doStuffD() {

    }
}
```

Reflections to get all uses of ImportantFunc (Ex: 100 uses of it) in package and uses this data to choose which function to use. The annotation is to help with the reflection since once it gets the data from @ImportantFunc, it then converts it to input for a library which does the actual choosing of which function to execute (this is internal and can not be modified). This could also be achieved with much longer and more annoying ways, but I was hoping to use annotations to simplify the process of defining all of these functions.

**Edit:**

Another way this could be solved is finding a way to group two annotations together.

Being able to do this would not be completely ideal, but would definitely make this much more workable:

```
public @interface Example {
    AnyTypeOfAnnotation[] set();
}
```

Comment: I just wrote it this way in order to generalize my problem and hopefully make it more strait forward.

Comment: I just re-read and I think I understand your use-case now. Is there a reason why order matters? Is it used in reflections or just something you see in Javadoc?

Comment: It is used in reflections as a qualifier for how the class or function will operate in the program.

Comment: Why do `A`, `B`, and `C` have to be annotations? As far as I can see, they could be just regular classes. --- Note: Annotations are attached to a *target*, e.g. `@D` is attached to class `SomeImportantClass`, but your `@B` and `@C` are not attached to anything, ergo they are not *annotations*. It is important to specify *what* can be annotated, so you should always specify `@Target` for your annotations.

Comment: I wanted to simplify the problem in order to make it more straightforward, in the end D would have to be an annotation.

Comment: There's no way to extend annotations, so this isn't possible the way you have it shown here. If you tell us more about what you're actually trying to do, maybe we can suggest an alternative.

Comment: The extends is just to give an analogy of how it would work.

Comment: Well, there's no other way to do subtyping, so that doesn't change what I said. There's no way to have an array of more than one type of annotation.

Comment: Is there a different way to achieve the same goal, but only D is an annotation?

Comment: Yes, maybe, and that's why I suggested that you tell us more about what you're doing. (For example: why does the order matter? Are Bs and Cs e.g. associated somehow?)

Answer (score 2):

One kludgy way to do this is to actually make `A` be a union of `B` and `C`. This means it has all the fields of *both* `B` and `C`, but you only ever use it as *either* a `B` *or* a `C`.

Here's a working example.

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;

enum NoType {;}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@interface A {
    Class<?> data()  default NoType.class; // field from B
    int      dataA() default 0;            // field from C
    String   dataB() default "";           // field from C
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@interface D {
    A[] value() default {};
}

class Foo {}
class Bar {}

class Example {
    @D({
        @A(data = Bar.class),
        @A(dataA = 5, dataB = "Bla"),
        @A(data = Foo.class)
    })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (A a : Example.class.getMethod("main", String[].class)
                        .getAnnotation(D.class).value()) {
            if (a.data() != NoType.class) {
                System.out.printf("B(%s)%n", a.data());
            } else {
                System.out.printf("C(dataA = %d, dataB = \"%s\")%n",
                    a.dataA(), a.dataB());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The [output of that program](https://ideone.com/EeV7BV) is:

```
B(class Bar)
C(dataA = 5, dataB = "Bla")
B(class Foo)
```

Of course, it's not a very pretty solution, but it does work.

Comment: Actually, this solution should work great (in terms of allowing different data types) when combined with mine. Just give `A` an attribute that returns `Class<?>[]` and another attribute that returns `Object[]`, then do the matching in reflection codes. Of course, the person writing the code has to be responsible for writing it right.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this would be sufficient for your use case:

```
public @interface A {
}

public @interface B extends A {
    //Gets stuff
    Class data();
}

public @interface C extends A {
    //Gets different stuff related to same goal
    int dataA();

    String dataB();
}

public @interface D {
    Class<? extends A>[] order();
}


@B(Bar.class)
@C(dataA = 5, dataB = "Bla")
@D(order = {B.class, C.class})
public class SomeImportantClass {

}
```

This method uses `D` annotation as a mean to retain annotation order. The bad part is that you cannot add multiple annotations of the same type.

There is another method that makes `A`, `B` and `C` into normal classes.

```
public abstract class AnnotationAttribute {
    public abstract Class<?>[] getDataTypes();
    public abstract Object[] getData();
}

public class B extends AnnotationAttribute {
    @Override public Class<?>[] getDataTypes() {
        return new Class<?>[] {Foo.class, Bar.class};
    }
    @Override public Object[] getData() {
        return new Object[] {new Foo(), new Bar()};
    }
}

public @interface D {
    Class<? extends AnnotationAttribute>[] data() default {};
}

@D(data = {B.class});
public class Test {
}
```

This method requires you to create one class for one concrete attribute type. This is because annotations have to be compile-time constant, and referencing via `Class` requires you to define the class out in code.

Comment: Not sure if you tried to compile this or not but the extends keyword is not allowed on @interface types.